# Parse HTML table from Outlook body fields to excel sheet

Tags: html, vba, parsing, outlook

I have a folder in Outlook where all the email messages from the other team will fall into that folder.

I want the VBA code that captures all the messages one by one in Excel sheet.

- The first slide is a sample email message with the fields with column order number.
- In the second slide, the capture results should be the same as the table in the Excel sheet. I have attached sample sheets for your reference.

I hope my question is clear to understand.

Thanks in advance.

I have a below where it captures the TO, subject, and received but not items in the body like String and table contents, I have attached a sample sheet for your reference. Let me know if you need anything else.

```vb
Sub getfolderitems()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    ' Set Outlook application object.
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim objNSpace As Object     ' Create and Set a NameSpace OBJECT.
    ' The GetNameSpace() method will represent a specified Namespace.
    Set objNSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim myFolder As Object  ' Create a folder object.
    Set myFolder = objNSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Dim otherFolder As Object
    Set otherFolder = myFolder.Folders("Fedx Request")'Insert subfolder'
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim iRows, iCols As Integer
    iRows = 2

    ' Loop through each item in the folder.
    For Each objItem In otherFolder.Items
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        
            Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
            Set objMail = objItem

           Cells(iRows, 1) = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
           Cells(iRows, 2) = objMail.To
            Cells(iRows, 3) = objMail.Subject
            Cells(iRows, 4) = objMail.ReceivedTime
        End If
        iRows = iRows + 1
    Next
    Set objMail = Nothing
  
    ' Release.
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objNSpace = Nothing
    Set otherFolder = Nothing
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: The attachments mentioned seem to be missing.